# C# JSON Parse get Key Value

Tags: c#, json, parsing, key

I am using Network JSON Plugin. I wanted to get JSON key. How I can get key?

My JSON Code is :

```
"kat1":{
"gg_id":"aaa",
"ozellik":{
"Tarih Aralığı":{"Combo":""
},
"Durum":{
"Combo":"Sıfır"
}
```

My C# Code is :

```
dynamic ozellik = veri.entegrekat; // My Parsed code is working

foreach (var kat in ozellik) // How  i get key
{
    MessageBox.Show("" + kat);    
}
```

When I am using `KeyValuePair<string,string>` or `<Object,Object>` I got error.

How I can retrieve value of key `kat1` from JSON?

Comment: You can use `Newtonsoft.Json` for deserializing the data and fetching key value pairs.

Comment: i deserializing json object , i have error KeyValuePairs
KeyValuePairs<string,string> or KeyValuePairs<Jtoken,Jtoken> is not working

Comment: what is the function of this line : `dynamic ozellik = veri.entegrekat;` ?

Comment: so what exception you are getting in this code :  `foreach (dynamic jv in user_data) { if(jv.id == id) { var veri = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.Seri‌​alizeObject(jv.data)‌​));`

Comment: Thanks now I fix

I fixed code 

 var ozellik = veri.entegrekat;
                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> result = ozellik.ToObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> kat in result)
                    {
                        
                        MessageBox.Show(""+kat.Key);
                    
                    }

Comment: ok great.you have fixed the code on your own

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Fixed

Code :

```
var ozellik = veri.entegrekat;
                    Dictionary<string, dynamic> result = ozellik.ToObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dynamic> kat in result)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show(""+kat.Key);

                    }
```